# SQL Server prepared statement with PHP - Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a prepared statement to SQL Server using PHP.
This is my (partial) code:

```
$tsql = "INSERT INTO CLIDES
            (STTIPANA,
            STCODCLI,
            STCODDES,
            STRAGSO1,
            STRAGSO2)
        VALUES 
            ('C',
            ?,
            '0000000',
            ?,
            ?
            )";
$params = array(
    &$id_customer,
    &$name1,
    &$name2,
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, $params);
if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {  
    echo "Statement executed.\n";  
} else {  
    echo "Statement could not be executed.\n";  
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

$conn is correctly valorized (before this query there's another one and it's working fine).

Result is an error and the string

> Statement could not be executed".

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [0] => IMSSP 
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP 
            [1] => -16 
            [code] => -16 
            [2] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified. 
            [message] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified. 
        ) 
    )
```

Using the following loop

```
foreach ($params as $i => $v) {
    echo $i . " - " . $v . "<br>";
}
```

I can read the 3 parameters (and relative index).

I tried to Google but I can't understand the reason of this problem. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `I can read the 3 parameters`...can you show us that output please

Comment: You are passing in the params as pointers, which is probably not understood by the `sqlsrv_prepare` function. Can you try it without the ampersands? Like: `$params = array($id_customer, $name1, $name2)`

Comment: `An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified` <- This should be a big clue

Comment: @WesselvanderLinden Suprised me too. But check [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) :)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the 3 parameters were objects (due to a particular call to a webservice) so the "echo" was fine (right strings) but the types were not strings. Hours wasted. Thank you everybody